# Creating packages with external dependencies

Tags: r, package, external, roxygen2

I have a package that I'm creating using `roxygen2`, the problem is that the most important dependent package (`Rgraphviz`) is not on CRAN but rather `bioconductor`.

What is the best and most hassle free way to get this dependency loaded when my package is installed? preferably through the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: How many functions are you using from `Rgraphvis`?  Sometimes you can try to get the author to let you use the code without depending on the package then cite their package in yours

Comment: Ya im currently only using one or two, but i do plan on extending the functionality of my package and that might require more functions from theirs. Would be useful to have access to the full suite of the package functions now and nip this problem in the bud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `DESCRIPTION` file put this line:

```
Suggests: Rgraphviz
```

and then in your R code use:

```
if (require(Rgraphviz)) { ... } else stop("Rgraphviz package could not be loaded")
```

The [psych package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=psych) is an example of a CRAN package that uses Rgraphviz so you can follow it.